# Spring Cassandra 3.0.1.RELEASE( Datastax 4.6+) log queries

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am using latest version of spring data cassandra which uses datastax 4.6

In older version there was a way to log slower and normal queries using **QueryLogger** and **Cluster**

However I am not able to find a way of logging queries and time taken in newer version

Answer (score 1):

In newer version **QueryLogger** is no longer available it was replaced with **RequestTracker**

> The Java driver provides a RequestTracker interface. You can specify an implementation of your
> own or use the provided RequestLogger implementation by configuring the properties in the
> datastax-java-driver.advanced.request-tracker namespace. The RequestLogger tracks every
> query your application executes and has options to enable logging for successful, failed, and slow
> queries. Use the slow query logger to identify queries that are not within your defined performance.

Configuration:

```
datastax-java-driver.advanced.request-tracker {
  class = RequestLogger

  logs {
    # Whether to log successful requests.
    success.enabled = true

    slow {
      # The threshold to classify a successful request as "slow". If this is unset, all
      # successful requests will be considered as normal.
      threshold = 1 second

      # Whether to log slow requests.
      enabled = true
    }

    # Whether to log failed requests.
    error.enabled = true

    # The maximum length of the query string in the log message. If it is longer than that, it
    # will be truncated.
    max-query-length = 500

    # Whether to log bound values in addition to the query string.
    show-values = true

    # The maximum length for bound values in the log message. If the formatted representation of
    # a value is longer than that, it will be truncated.
    max-value-length = 50

    # The maximum number of bound values to log. If a request has more values, the list of
    # values will be truncated.
    max-values = 50

    # Whether to log stack traces for failed queries. If this is disabled, the log will just
    # include the exception's string representation (generally the class name and message).
    show-stack-traces = true
}
```

[More details.](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/request_tracker/)